# Problems initializing SD card with MSP430

Tags: spi, msp430, sd, msp

I've been working on some code to talk to an SD card with the MSP430. I can't get the card to enter into idle mode, and I'm actually pretty stumped as to why. I've looked at the microcontroller output with a logic analyzer and everything looks as it should. I've tried a few different cards and SD card adapters with the same results so it seems like a code issue. I'm initializing the SD card with this code:

```
void MMC_initSPI(void){
//SOMI: 3.1
//SIMO: 3.0
//CLK: 3.2
//CS: 1.4
//chip select
SD_CSn_PxDIR|=SD_CSn_PIN;
SD_CSn_PxOUT|=SD_CSn_PIN;

UCB0CTL1 = UCSSEL_2 | UCSWRST;  // source USCI clock from SMCLK, put USCI in reset mode
UCB0CTL0 |= SPI_MODE_0;         // SPI MODE 0 - CPOL=0 CPHA=0
                                // note: UCCKPH is inverted from CPHA
//do I need to do this??
UCB0BR0 = LOBYTE(SPI_400kHz);   // set initial speed
UCB0BR1 = HIBYTE(SPI_400kHz);

P3SEL  |= BIT0 + BIT1 + BIT2;   // configure for USCI

UCB0CTL1 &= ~UCSWRST;           // release for operation
}
```

and then sending `0xFF` within a for loop 11 times (well within the 71 clock pulses needed to awaken the card to new data) before using the `mmc_GoIdle()` function, which is as follows:

```
char mmc_GoIdle(){
char response=0x01;
CS_LOW();

//Send Command 0 to put MMC in SPI mode
mmcSendCmd(MMC_GO_IDLE_STATE, 0, 0x95);
//Now wait for READY RESPONSE
if(mmcGetResponse()!=0x01)
return MMC_INIT_ERROR;

while(response==0x01)
{
  CS_HIGH();
spiSendByte(0xff);
CS_LOW();
mmcSendCmd(MMC_SEND_OP_COND,0x00,0xff);
response=mmcGetResponse();
}
CS_HIGH();
spiSendByte(0xff);
return (MMC_SUCCESS);
}
```

but it always returns
`MMC_INIT_ERROR`. Can anyone spot anything obviously wrong? The logic analyzer tells me it's returning `0x00` and not `0x01` as it should. Any ideas?

Answer (score -3):

Try with SPI_MODE_1 it will work.

Comment: Would you care to explain *why* this change will work?